# How to dynamically select previous sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the implementation of non-standard solutions. So my HTML:

```
<a href="#6" id="page-link-6">6</a>
<a href="#7" id="page-link-7" class="active">7</a>
<a href="#8" id="page-link-8">8</a>
```

And my poor, incompetent js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 0) {
        $("#page-link-6").addClass("active" );
   }
});
```

I have selected (active) link. I need add same (active) class to previus link when user scroll at top of document. This example have active #page-link-7. Previus is 6. So when user scroll at top, class "active" will be added for #page-link-6. But if current active page-link is 9, how can i go to 8 dynamically? I hope someone can help me here. Thanks.

Comment: If you want, you can use a plugin: https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

Comment: I am still not sure about what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is just find the `next` and `previous sibling` of `active` link and add class to it like below:

Wrap all the `<a>` in a separate `class`

```
<div class="Links">
   <a href="#6" id="page-link-6">6</a>
   <a href="#7" id="page-link-7" class="active">7</a>
   <a href="#8" id="page-link-8">8</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var activeLink=$('.Links').children().find('.active').removeClass('active');
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 0) 
{
      $(activeLink).prev().addClass('active');
}
else
{
     $(activeLink).next().addClass('active');
}
```

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hzd6134p/2/)**

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var activeLink=$('.Links').find('.active');
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 0) 
    {

          if($(activeLink).prev().length>0)
          {
             $(activeLink).removeClass('active');
             $(activeLink).prev().addClass('active');
          }
    }
    else
    {
        if($(activeLink).next().length>0)
        {
            $(activeLink).removeClass('active');
            $(activeLink).next().addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the element that is currently active, then use jQuerys `.prev()` method to find the "previous" link.
Something along the likes of

```
$('.active').prev().addClass("active" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but sounds like [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) may be better for you.

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    $('a').toggleClass("active");
});
```

[Simple Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaT3P/195/).